# Spring configuration issue with abstract parent class and child class

Tags: java, mysql, spring, dependency-injection, spring-ioc

I am trying to get the following code to work. Basically i have a table called alert_settings in a mysql database. Below is how i configured it and the classes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        ">

    <!-- DriverManagerDataSource : Spring simplest implementation of a DataSource (doesn�??t support database connection pooling)-->

    <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url"              value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username"         value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password"         value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>


    <!-- The properties file containing the values for the JDBC datasource-->   
    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>


    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="abstractBaseClass" abstract="true" class="org.jay.dao.impl.spring.commons.GenericDAO">
      <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="alertSettingDAO" class="org.jay.dao.impl.spring.AlertSettingDAOImplSpring" parent="abstractBaseClass">     
      <!--Override the value of the abstract based class if necessary-->
      <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Below is my Abstract Generic DAO, Alert settings DAO interface and actual DAO class.

- Abstract Generic DAO

  ```
  public abstract class GenericDAO<T> {

  /**
   * The DataSource providing the connections (injected by Spring)
   */
  @Resource(name="dataSource")
  private DataSource dataSource;

  /**
   * The auto-incremented column name if any (null if none)
   */
  private final String  autoIncrColumnName ;

  /**
   * The columns types for each value to be inserted with an auto-incremented key (null if no auto-incremented column)
   */
  private final int[]   insertJdbcTypes ;

  /**
   * Constructor for a standard table (without auto-incremented column)
   */
  protected GenericDAO() {
      super();
      this.autoIncrColumnName = null ;
      this.insertJdbcTypes = null ;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor for a table with an auto-incremented key
   * @param autoIncrColumnName
   * @param insertJdbcTypes
   */
  protected GenericDAO(String autoIncrColumnName, int[] insertJdbcTypes) {
      super();
      this.autoIncrColumnName = autoIncrColumnName ;
      this.insertJdbcTypes = insertJdbcTypes ;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the SQL SELECT REQUEST to be used to retrieve the bean data from the database
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract String  getSqlSelect();

  /**
   * Returns the SQL INSERT REQUEST to be used to insert the bean in the database
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract String  getSqlInsert();

  /**
   * Returns the SQL UPDATE REQUEST to be used to update the bean in the database
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract String  getSqlUpdate();

  /**
   * Returns the SQL DELETE REQUEST to be used to delete the bean from the database
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract String  getSqlDelete();

  /**
   * Returns the SQL COUNT REQUEST to be used to check if the bean exists in the database
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract String  getSqlCount();

  /**
   * Returns the SQL COUNT REQUEST to be used to count all the beans present in the database
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract String  getSqlCountAll();

  /**
   * Returns the values to be used in the SQL INSERT PreparedStatement
   * @param bean
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract Object[] getValuesForInsert(T bean) ; 

  /**
   * Returns the values to be used in the SQL UPDATE PreparedStatement
   * @param bean
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract Object[] getValuesForUpdate(T bean) ; 

  /**
   * Returns the values to be used as Primary Key in a SQL WHERE clause in a PreparedStatement
   * @param bean
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract Object[] getValuesForPrimaryKey(T bean);

  /**
   * Returns a RowMapper for the given bean
   * @param bean
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract RowMapper<T>  getRowMapper(T bean);

  /**
   * Returns a RowMapper for a new bean instance
   * @return
   */
  protected abstract RowMapper<T>  getRowMapper();

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  private void log(String msg) {
      //System.out.println("[DAO LOG] : " + msg );
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Returns an instance of Spring 'JdbcTemplate' for the current DataSource
   * @return
   */
  private JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Loads the given bean from the database using its current primary key (SQL SELECT)<br>
   * If found the given bean is populated 
   * @param bean
   * @return true if found and loaded, false if not found
   */
  protected boolean doSelect(T bean) {

      log("Select using a bean instance : " + bean );
      Object[] primaryKey = getValuesForPrimaryKey(bean);
      log("Select using a bean instance : Primary Key = " + toString(primaryKey) );
      RowMapper<T> rowMapper = getRowMapper(bean) ;
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate();
      //--- Try to find the record. NB : Spring throws "EmptyResultDataAccessException" if not found
      try {
          T beanFound = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getSqlSelect(), primaryKey, rowMapper);
          if ( beanFound != bean ) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected instance returned by JdbcTemplate");
          }
          return true ;
      } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
          // Nothing to do, just return "not found"
          return false;
      }
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Loads a bean from the database using the given primary key (SQL SELECT)<br>
   * @param primaryKey
   * @return the bean found or null if not found
   */
  protected T doSelect(Object[] primaryKey) {
      log("Select by Primary Key : " + toString(primaryKey) );
      RowMapper<T> rowMapper = getRowMapper() ;
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate();
      //--- Try to find the record. NB : Spring throws "EmptyResultDataAccessException" if not found
      try {
          return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getSqlSelect(), primaryKey, rowMapper);
      } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
          // Nothing to do, just return null
          return null;
      }
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Inserts the given bean in the database (SQL INSERT)
   * @param bean
   */
  protected void doInsert(T bean) {
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); 
      //--- Execute INSERT
      int result = jdbcTemplate.update(getSqlInsert(), getValuesForInsert(bean) );
      if ( result != 1 ) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected return value after INSERT : " + result + " (1 expected) ");
      }
  }   

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Returns a 'PreparedStatementCreator' usable with a 'KeyHolder' for an insert with an auto-incremented key
   * @param bean
   * @return
   */
  private PreparedStatementCreator getPreparedStatementCreator(final T bean) {
      //log("getPreparedStatementCreator : auto incr col = " + autoIncrColumnName  );
      //log("getPreparedStatementCreator : sql insert = " + getSqlInsert() );
      PreparedStatementCreatorFactory factory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(getSqlInsert(), this.insertJdbcTypes) ;

      factory.setGeneratedKeysColumnNames(new String[]{autoIncrColumnName});
      //log("before newPreparedStatementCreator : values for insert = " + toString(getValuesForInsert(bean)));
      PreparedStatementCreator psc = factory.newPreparedStatementCreator(getValuesForInsert(bean));
      //log("after newPreparedStatementCreator ");
      return psc ;
  }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Inserts the given bean in the database (SQL INSERT) with an auto-incremented key
   * @param bean
   * @return the value of the generated key
   */
  protected long doInsertAutoIncr(final T bean) {
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); 
      // GeneratedKeyHolder : the default implementation of the KeyHolder interface, to be used for holding auto-generated keys 
      KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder(); 

      int result = jdbcTemplate.update(getPreparedStatementCreator(bean), keyHolder );

      if ( result != 1 ) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected return value after INSERT : " + result + " (1 expected) ");
      }

      //--- Retrieve the generated value
      Number key = keyHolder.getKey(); // Single numeric generated key
      if ( key != null ) {
          return key.longValue();
      }
      else {
          throw new RuntimeException("Cannot retrive generated key after INSERT : KeyHolder returns null");
      }
  }   
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Inserts the given bean in the database (SQL INSERT) with an auto-incremented column (usually the primary key)
   * @param bean
   * @return the generated value for the auto-incremented column
   */
  protected Long doInsertAutoIncrOLD(T bean ) {

      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); 
      // GeneratedKeyHolder : the default implementation of the KeyHolder interface, to be used for holding auto-generated keys 
      KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder(); 

      //--- FORM 2 with only the KeyHolder
      int result = jdbcTemplate.update(getSqlInsert(), getValuesForInsert(bean), keyHolder, new String[]{autoIncrColumnName} );

      if ( result != 1 ) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected return value after INSERT : " + result + " (1 expected) ");
      }

      //--- Retrieve the generated value
      Number key = keyHolder.getKey(); // Single numeric generated key
      if ( key != null ) {
          return key.longValue();
      }
      else {
          throw new RuntimeException("Cannot retrive generated key after INSERT : KeyHolder returns null");
      }
  }   

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Updates the given bean in the database (SQL UPDATE)
   * @param bean the bean to be updated
   * @return the JDBC return code (i.e. the row count affected by the UPDATE operation : 0 or 1 )
   */
  protected int doUpdate(T bean) {
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); 
      //--- Execute UPDATE
      int result = jdbcTemplate.update( getSqlUpdate(), getValuesForUpdate(bean) );
      if ( result != 0 && result != 1 ) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected return value after UPDATE : " + result + " (0 or 1 expected) ");
      }
      return result ;
  }   
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
   * Deletes the given bean in the database (SQL DELETE)
   * @param bean the bean to be deleted (containing the Primary Key)
   * @return the JDBC return code (i.e. the row count affected by the DELETE operation : 0 or 1 )
   */
  protected int doDelete(T bean) {
      return doDelete( getValuesForPrimaryKey(bean) ) ;
  }


  protected int doDelete(Object[] primaryKey) {
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); 
      //--- Execute DELETE
      int result = jdbcTemplate.update(getSqlDelete(), primaryKey);
      if ( result != 0 && result != 1 ) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected return value after DELETE : " + result + " (0 or 1 expected) ");
      }
      return result ;
  }


  protected boolean doExists(T bean) {
      return doExists( getValuesForPrimaryKey(bean) );
  }


  protected boolean doExists(Object[] primaryKey) {
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); 
      long count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getSqlCount(), primaryKey, Long.class);
      return count > 0 ;
  }


  protected long doCountAll() {
      JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); 
      return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getSqlCountAll(), Long.class);
  }


  protected String toString(Object[] objects) {
      if ( objects != null ) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.append("[");
          int i = 0 ;
          for ( Object o : objects ) {
              if ( i > 0 ) {
                  sb.append("|");
              }
              sb.append(o.toString());
              i++;
          }
          sb.append("]");
          return sb.toString();
      }
      else {
          return "null" ;
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- AlertSettingDAO interface

  ```
  public interface AlertSettingDAO {


      /**
       * Finds a bean by its primary key 
       * @param userToken
       * @return the bean found or null if not found 
       */
      public AlertSetting find( String userToken ) ;

      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      /**
       * Loads the given bean, it is supposed to contains the primary key value(s) in its attribute(s)<br>
       * If found, the given instance is populated with the values retrieved from the database<br>
       * If not found, the given instance remains unchanged
       * @param alertSetting
       * @return true if found, false if not found
       */
      public boolean load( AlertSetting alertSetting ) ;

      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      /**
       * Inserts the given bean in the database 
       * @param alertSetting
       */
      public void insert(AlertSetting alertSetting) ;

      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      /**
       * Updates the given bean in the database 
       * @param alertSetting
       * @return
       */
      public int update(AlertSetting alertSetting) ;

      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      /**
       * Deletes the record in the database using the given primary key value(s) 
       * @param userToken
       * @return
       */
      public int delete( String userToken ) ;

      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      /**
       * Deletes the given bean in the database 
       * @param alertSetting
       * @return
       */
      public int delete( AlertSetting alertSetting ) ;

      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      /**
       * Checks the existence of a record in the database using the given primary key value(s)
       * @param userToken
       * @return
       */
      public boolean exists( String userToken ) ;


      public boolean exists( AlertSetting alertSetting ) ;


      public long count() ;

  }
  ```
- and 3. AlertSettingDAO implementation class

@Repository
public class AlertSettingDAOImplSpring extends GenericDAO implements AlertSettingDAO {

```
private final static String SQL_SELECT = 
    "select user_token, sms_enabled, sms_settle_enabled, sms_load_enabled, sms_unload_enabled, sms_auth_enabled, sms_decline_enabled, sms_chargeback_enabled, sms_promo_enabled, sms_flagged_for_failures, 2way_enabled, email_alert_enabled from alert_setting where user_token = ?";


private final static String SQL_INSERT = 
    "insert into alert_setting ( user_token, sms_enabled, sms_settle_enabled, sms_load_enabled, sms_unload_enabled, sms_auth_enabled, sms_decline_enabled, sms_chargeback_enabled, sms_promo_enabled, sms_flagged_for_failures, 2way_enabled, email_alert_enabled ) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";

private final static String SQL_UPDATE = 
    "update alert_setting set sms_enabled = ?, sms_settle_enabled = ?, sms_load_enabled = ?, sms_unload_enabled = ?, sms_auth_enabled = ?, sms_decline_enabled = ?, sms_chargeback_enabled = ?, sms_promo_enabled = ?, sms_flagged_for_failures = ?, 2way_enabled = ?, email_alert_enabled = ? where user_token = ?";

private final static String SQL_DELETE = 
    "delete from alert_setting where user_token = ?";

private final static String SQL_COUNT_ALL = 
    "select count(*) from alert_setting";

private final static String SQL_COUNT = 
    "select count(*) from alert_setting where user_token = ?";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * DAO constructor
 */
public AlertSettingDAOImplSpring() {
    super();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public AlertSetting find( String userToken ) {
    Object[] primaryKey = new Object[] { userToken };
    return super.doSelect(primaryKey);      
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public boolean load( AlertSetting alertSetting ) {
    return super.doSelect(alertSetting) ;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public void insert(AlertSetting alertSetting) {
    super.doInsert(alertSetting);
}   

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public int update(AlertSetting alertSetting) {
    return super.doUpdate(alertSetting);
}   

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public int delete( String userToken ) {
    Object[] primaryKey = new Object[] { userToken };
    return super.doDelete(primaryKey);      
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public int delete( AlertSetting alertSetting ) {
    return super.doDelete(alertSetting);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public boolean exists( String userToken ) {
    Object[] primaryKey = new Object[] { userToken };
    return super.doExists(primaryKey);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public boolean exists( AlertSetting alertSetting ) {
    return super.doExists(alertSetting);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * DAO interface implementation
 */
@Override
public long count() {
    return super.doCountAll();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Super class abstract methods implementation
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected String getSqlSelect() {
    return SQL_SELECT ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected String getSqlInsert() {
    return SQL_INSERT ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected String getSqlUpdate() {
    return SQL_UPDATE ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected String getSqlDelete() {
    return SQL_DELETE ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected String getSqlCount() {
    return SQL_COUNT ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected String getSqlCountAll() {
    return SQL_COUNT_ALL ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected Object[] getValuesForInsert(AlertSetting alertSetting)  {
    return new Object[] {
        //--- Returns PRIMARY KEY and DATA ( for SQL "SET x=?, y=?, ..." )
        alertSetting.getUserToken() , // "user_token" : java.lang.String
        alertSetting.getSmsEnabled() , // "sms_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsSettleEnabled() , // "sms_settle_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsLoadEnabled() , // "sms_load_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsUnloadEnabled() , // "sms_unload_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsAuthEnabled() , // "sms_auth_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsDeclineEnabled() , // "sms_decline_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsChargebackEnabled() , // "sms_chargeback_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsPromoEnabled() , // "sms_promo_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsFlaggedForFailures() , // "sms_flagged_for_failures" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getTwoWayEnabled() , // "2way_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getEmailAlertEnabled()  // "email_alert_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
    };
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected Object[] getValuesForUpdate(AlertSetting alertSetting) {
    return new Object[] {       
        //--- Returns DATA first ( for SQL "SET x=?, y=?, ..." )
        alertSetting.getSmsEnabled(), // "sms_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsSettleEnabled(), // "sms_settle_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsLoadEnabled(), // "sms_load_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsUnloadEnabled(), // "sms_unload_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsAuthEnabled(), // "sms_auth_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsDeclineEnabled(), // "sms_decline_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsChargebackEnabled(), // "sms_chargeback_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsPromoEnabled(), // "sms_promo_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getSmsFlaggedForFailures(), // "sms_flagged_for_failures" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getTwoWayEnabled(), // "2way_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        alertSetting.getEmailAlertEnabled(), // "email_alert_enabled" : java.lang.Integer
        //--- Returns PRIMARY KEY at the end ( for SQL "WHERE key=?, ..." )
        alertSetting.getUserToken()  // "user_token" : java.lang.String
    };
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected Object[] getValuesForPrimaryKey(AlertSetting alertSetting)  {
    return new Object[] {
        //--- Returns PRIMARY KEY values ( for SQL "WHERE key=?, ..." )
        alertSetting.getUserToken()  // "user_token" : java.lang.String
    };
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected RowMapper<AlertSetting> getRowMapper(AlertSetting o)  {
    //--- RowMapper to populate the given bean instance
    return new AlertSettingRowMapper(o) ;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected RowMapper<AlertSetting> getRowMapper()  {
    //--- RowMapper to populate a new bean instance
    return new AlertSettingRowMapper( new AlertSetting() ) ;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Populates the given bean with the data retrieved from the given ResultSet
 * @param rs
 * @param alertSetting
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private void populateBean(ResultSet rs, AlertSetting alertSetting) throws SQLException {

    //--- Set data from ResultSet to Bean attributes
    alertSetting.setUserToken(rs.getString("user_token")); // java.lang.String
    alertSetting.setSmsEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsSettleEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_settle_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsSettleEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsLoadEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_load_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsLoadEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsUnloadEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_unload_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsUnloadEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsAuthEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_auth_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsAuthEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsDeclineEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_decline_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsDeclineEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsChargebackEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_chargeback_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsChargebackEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsPromoEnabled(rs.getInt("sms_promo_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsPromoEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setSmsFlaggedForFailures(rs.getInt("sms_flagged_for_failures")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setSmsFlaggedForFailures(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setTwoWayEnabled(rs.getInt("2way_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setTwoWayEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
    alertSetting.setEmailAlertEnabled(rs.getInt("email_alert_enabled")); // java.lang.Integer
    if ( rs.wasNull() ) { alertSetting.setEmailAlertEnabled(null); }; // not primitive number => keep null value if any
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Specific inner class for 'RowMapper' implementation
 */
private class AlertSettingRowMapper implements RowMapper<AlertSetting> {


    private final AlertSetting bean ;


    AlertSettingRowMapper(AlertSetting bean) {
        this.bean = bean ;
    }

    @Override
    public AlertSetting mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        populateBean(rs, this.bean);
        return this.bean;
    }
}
```

}

this is my main class

```
public class Test {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("spring-context.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
    AlertSettingDAOImplSpring a = (AlertSettingDAOImplSpring) factory.getBean("alertSettingDAO");
    System.out.println(a.find("Anil").toString());
}  
}  

Error creating bean with name 'alertSettingDAO' defined in class path resource [spring-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [org.jay.dao.impl.spring.AlertSettingDAOImplSpring]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Where am i going wrong? How to do it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, you don't have getters and setters for DataSource in your classes.

Also your Spring configuration is wrong, you are using `value="dataSource"` and spring expects those classes to have getters and setters of string for property dataSource. You have to change them to use `ref="dataSource"` like in the following:

```
<bean id="abstractBaseClass" abstract="true" class="org.jay.dao.impl.spring.commons.GenericDAO">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="alertSettingDAO" class="org.jay.dao.impl.spring.AlertSettingDAOImplSpring" parent="abstractBaseClass">     
  <!--Override the value of the abstract based class if necessary-->
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Also remove @Resource annotation

```
private DataSource dataSource;
```

And make sure getters and setters are created in the classes for which you are trying to inject object reference.

If you don't want getters and setters remove `<property name="dataSource"...` declarations from Spring configuration and use @Autowired instead:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```